# How to close sidenav on a href click

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html, sidenav

The navigation works fine but the sidenav should close when a link is clicked. 
Because it is a onepage. How can I do that? Can someone help me please.

Code:

```js
function openNav() {
  document.getElementById("mySidenav").style.width = "250px";
}

function closeNav() {
  document.getElementById("mySidenav").style.width = "0";
}
```

```css
.sidenav {
  height: 100%;
  width: 0;
  position: fixed;
  z-index: 1;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  background-color: #111;
  overflow-x: hidden;
  transition: 0.5s;
  padding-top: 60px;
}
```

```html
<div id="mySidenav" class="sidenav">
  <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="closebtn" onclick="closeNav()">&times;</a>
  <a id="nav" href="#about">About</a>
  <a id="nav" href="#service">Services</a>
  <a id="nav" href="#contact">contact</a>

</div>
<p>Click to open</p>
<span style="font-size:30px;cursor:pointer" onclick="openNav()">&#9776; open</span>
```

The sidenav should close when a link is clicked

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code works perfectly. You only seem to have forgotten to add `closenav()` to the `onlick` events on the actual links.

```js
function openNav() {
  document.getElementById("mySidenav").style.width = "250px";
}

function closeNav() {
  document.getElementById("mySidenav").style.width = "0";
}
```

```css
.sidenav {
  height: 100%;
  width: 0;
  position: fixed;
  z-index: 1;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  background-color: #111;
  overflow-x: hidden;
  transition: 0.5s;
  padding-top: 60px;
}
```

```html
<div id="mySidenav" class="sidenav">
  <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="closebtn" onclick="closeNav()">&times;</a>
  <a id="nav" href="#about" onclick="closeNav()">About</a>
  <a id="nav" href="#service" onclick="closeNav()">Services</a>
  <a id="nav" href="#contact" onclick="closeNav()">contact</a>

</div>
<p>Click to open</p>
<span style="font-size:30px;cursor:pointer" onclick="openNav()">&#9776; open</span>
```

Comment: I can't see the wood for the trees. Thank you very much NSevens !

Comment: No problem :) glad to "help" :)

Answer (score 0):

Try this one:

**HTML:**

```
<div id="mySidenav" class="sidenav jsSideNav">
          <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="">&times;</a>
          <a id="nav" href="#about">About</a>
          <a id="nav" href="#service">Services</a>
          <a id="nav" href="#contact">contact</a>
    </div>
    <p>Click to open</p>
    <span style="font-size:30px;cursor:pointer" class="jsToggleNav">&#9776; open</span>
```

**CSS:**

```
.sidenav {
  height: 100%;
  width: 0;
  position: fixed;
  z-index: 1;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  background-color: #111;
  overflow-x: hidden;
  transition: 0.5s;
  padding-top: 60px;
}
.sidenav.active {
    width: 250px;
}
```

**JS:**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
        $(".jsToggleNav").on('click', function(){
            if($(".jsSideNav").hasClass('active')) {
                $(".jsSideNav").removeClass('active');
            } else {
                $(".jsSideNav").addClass('active');
            }
        })
    });
```

I am assuming that you are using jquery, also follow the naming convention of class name that specifically used for js operations.

Hope this can help you.